# how to add a status message on a grails respond

Tags: grails, groovy

I have created a method that is called after every uncatched exception and respond a gson view:

```
void handleError(){
        respond([status: 500, view: "/customErr"], [
                code      : 500,
                message   : "whatever internal error",
        ])
}
```

this works fine but the main problem that I have is that my client (another server acting as client) is receiving a http response with a 500 status but the status message is null. I've checked the respond docs and I don't see a property message or something. 
this if what my client receive:

```
wslite.rest.RESTClientException: 500 null
```

and that null is the response's status message that is not set by grails 
How can I add a detail message on my respond? idyllically something like this:

```
  respond([status: 500, statusMessage: "my custom 
    message", view: "/customErr"], [
                code      : 500,
                message   : "whatever internal error",
        ])
```

Comment: typically a response from a controller responds with content and  status (default success). https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html. Status codes as per link are an integer value.https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-vue-springsecurity-demo/blob/master/server/grails-app/controllers/demo/CustomRestController.groovy#L82 This is how you typically send whatever with whatever status code - then the client whether a browser or another server with http client would read response and status and based on status do something with the response

Comment: not helpful, I understand what you are saying but my problem is that my client is receiving the response with the correct status code and my custom json but the client does not have a detail message for the respond, instead, I see in my client's log:

wslite.rest.RESTClientException: 401 null

where null is the response detailed message that is not set by grails and I don't like having this null value on my logs.

Comment: `status: Errors.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` This appears to be an internal thing  custom made - does this resolve to integer 401 response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED  ?  Don't think anyone remotely without being to work out what that code maps to when it sends it is going to be give much help - the principal of all http clients are the same based on error code do something which user defines. Can you try `response status: response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, text: 'some error message' ` see how that goes

Comment: edited the question, Errors.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR was just a constant for the code integer, I edited the question because I don't think it's relevant. The respond status expects the integer code of the HTTP response, I tried adding text: 'some error message' as you suggested but nothing changes.

Comment: Updated the question again, the error code is not the problem!!!!! 
that's completely fine, I created the question fast and I wrote 401 instead of 500 on the message. The question is updated now, sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: Very confused really the method above you have shown with two arrays is not standard or documented as such https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/respond.html. The main issue is you are attempting to render a view when it is an error as well as an error : `[status: 500, statusMessage: "my custom 
    message", view: "/customErr"`. If it's a view then the view should present that message logic within in - if not a view then something like this `import grails.converters.JSON
 
def jsonObject =  [code: 500,message:"whatever internal error"] as JSON
render  jsonObject , status: 500`.

Comment: I think you will need to outline or show in a basic sample how the other side is working - you have shown 1 side and the issue appears to be the processing of what is not shown - perhaps create a sample github project - basic example but as per above your entire method the respond appears to be making up new components and your question appears to ask on how to do this - basically the way is to encode that as a json and do like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grails uses [Servlet API’s HttpServletResponse](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) to build [response](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/response.html).

now check the java doc for [HttpServletResponse](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) class.

there are only 2 methods to define status message:

- [`void setStatus(int sc, String msg)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus-int-java.lang.String-) **Deprecated**. As of version 2.1, due to ambiguous meaning of the message parameter. To set a status code use setStatus(int), to send an error with a description use sendError(int, String).
- [`void sendError(int sc, String msg)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError-int-java.lang.String-) Sends an error response to the client using the specified status and clears the buffer. The server defaults to creating the response to look like an **HTML-formatted server error page** containing the specified message, setting the content type to "text/html".

The first one is deprecated. The second one sends the status message, but it will not send the body - mainly this used for fatal errors...

So, officially by servlet documentation there is no way to send both: message and body in response.

---

The question is tricky. Because according to Apache Tomcat the "custom status message" feature will be removed starting from version 9: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html#Other

But according to [RFC2616 sec 6.1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1) : The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- **they MAY be replaced** by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.

Comment: Then, if you were in my case you would use the custom error json on the response's body and ignore the client null message? 

That works just fine, it is not that I have any kind of problem but I don't like having so many nulls on my logs.

Comment: I prefer to use custom json body because you could add some details like error code, stacktrace, etc. however you are the designer of your api

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, and may not solve your issue depending on how much control you have over the application that receives the error, but you can add error messages to the header of the response which should pass through to the client (if it knows to check for them).

```
String errorMessage = "Whatever Internal Server Error"
response.addHeader("custom-error", errorMessage)
response.sendError(500, errorMessage)
```

That'll send the message in the header and as the response message...  I do not know if this works with `respond()` or how that interacts with the `response` object in the controller...  but if you're responding to render a view as the error page, you should be able to add the message to the `model` included in the `respond()` call and show that on the error page (at least, I'd think so).